# Documentation should allow changes directly under review of a new topic

Tags: discussion, feature-request, documentation

Right now resubmitting the topic, which is requires, strips all the useful comments made.

As an example, a GitHub pull requests updates dynamically, reflecting that some comments become addressed. Same can be done with Google Docs.

I am aware of the fact that this can be done for normal topics with "request improvement", but I think it should work this way for new topics too.